# How did Euler obtain these two formulae? Are they correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I am reading this book on trigonometric series, "Тригонометрические ряды от Эйлера до Лебега" (Trigonometric series from Euler to Lebesgue) , it is in Russian, and my Russian is abysmal. But there is a very interesting formula, it is:

$$\dfrac{1-r\cos(x)}{1-2r\cos(x)+r^2}=1+r\cos(x)+r^2\cos(2x)+r^{3}\cos(3x)...$$

$$\dfrac{r\sin(x)}{1-2r\cos(x)+r^2}=r\sin(x)+r^2\sin(2x)+r^{3}\sin(3x)...$$

As $r=1$ or $r=-1$

We have: $$-\dfrac{1}{2}=\cos(x)+2\cos(x)+3\cos(3x)+...$$

$$\dfrac{1}{2}=\cos(x)-2\cos(x)+3\cos(3x)+...$$

He integrated the second series and obtain the trigonometric series:

$$\dfrac{x}{2}=\sin(x)-\dfrac{1}{2}\sin(2x)+\dfrac{1}{3}\sin(3x)-...$$

The first and second series are divergent, so I think the result doesn't make sense, although the formal method of deriving it may seem correct.

The third series is correct on the interval $[\pi, -\pi]$, because the series expansion converges to that function (Correct me if I am wrong here, I haven't studied Fourier series).

I wish to ask how did he obtain the above formula? Are these formula incorrect because the issue of convergence? Also, which papers contain these results?

Comment: Yes, let me correct it.

Comment: Yes, for functions that aren't $2\pi$ periodic, like $x/2$, their Fourier series will only converge on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: The first formula, at least numerically, appears very much incorrect. See [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dfg0i5fkps)

Comment: You did some numerical tests with computational software? Could you give a numerical example where the result is contradictory?

Comment: @K.defaoite Why did you say that appears to be incorrect? the link you post of Desmos support the correctness of the formula. Just set N big enough and |t|<1

Comment: @jjgamath, I am not sure if I can trust Desmos. But how do you know if the graph proves the correctness of the formulae? When the graph of both sides of the equations match so that they are coincide with each other?

Comment: @JamesWarthington See the edit of my answer. By the way, i know the graphs don't prove nothing, but they help a lot to make conjectures.

Comment: @jjgamath Well I set the N big and $|t|<1$, they don't match each other. If I set |t| around 0.4, then they diverge from each other.

Comment: Are we looking at the same page? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dfg0i5fkps 
For t = 0.4 and N = 3 graphs are already very close. For bigger N they're indistinguishable.

Comment: @jjamath N does indeed match, but if t is larger, than the two graphs do no match each other. Maybe this is correct only with some conditions of |t|?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the fact that $|t|<1$.

Comment: @jjamath So they are only correct for some |t|, but not all? There is no conditions on |t| on the page of that book.

Comment: @JamesWarthington As I said, see my answer. The formulas can be proved using the geometric series, if you do the calculations you'll see that it's necessary to have |t|<1.

Comment: @jjamath Ok, I see your point. But how do you prove it? Is it very difficult?

Comment: @jjamath, also, these series are not strictly geometric, the coefficients form a geometric sequence, but the argument of sin(x) and cos(x) forms an arithmetic progression.

Comment: @JamesWarthington That's why my answer suggests first using the formulas for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, to **turn them** into geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

In Euler's time, the concept of convergence had not been properly defined. Much of his work lacks the rigor we are now used to.

At that time, even renowned mathematicians used to do things like manipulate divergent series freely and, at the end of their calculations, examine the result. If it made sense, they save it, if not, they discard it.

They developed an intuition about what could and could not be done, but they did not have the theory to back up many of the algebraic manipulations they did.

The formulas can be proved using $\displaystyle \cos(x) =\frac{e^{i x}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and $\displaystyle\sin(x) =\frac{e^{i x} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$ to turn the sums into geometric series.

Comment: I know, but are these results, particularly the two formula, essentially correct. Because it claims that the function of the left side is the convergent limit of the function series on the right side. How true is this formula.

Comment: @JamesWarthington See the edit of my answer.

Comment: Do you mind to do it? I am particularly interested in the left hand side. If it is too time consuming, maybe another time.